# How to find path to android image and create File from Uri

Tags: android, android-file, android-contentresolver

I have a problem with converting Uri path to URI(to create a file).

My code is:

```
private void uploadImageToServer(Uri path){
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    android.database.Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(path, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return;

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    File file = new File(filePath);
}
```

However my cursor is null.

My "Uri path" parameter from function is:
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/IMG_20170411_170952.jpg`

I was following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@adinugroho/upload-image-from-android-app-using-retrofit-2-ae6f922b184c

Answer (score 3):

try this and and I highly recommend not using

```
content://
```

just use it as

```
content:

String imagePath = "";
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        if (data.toString().contains("content:")) {
            imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(targetUri);
        } else if (data.toString().contains("file:")) {
            imagePath = targetUri.getPath();
        } else {
            imagePath = null;
        }


 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
My "Uri path" parameter from function is: 
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/IMG_20170411_170952.jpg
```

Then the path you are after is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/IMG_20170411_170952.jpg
```

Code

```
private void uploadImageToServer(Uri uri){
   String filePath = uri.toString().replace("file://", "" );

   File file = new File(filePath);
}
```

Maybe you could even use uri.getPath() directly. Please check.

Comment: Yes, i check this on debugger, but how to make this properly?

Comment: What is the problem you encounter to remove the start of that string? There is a String replace() function for it isn't it?

Comment: I want to know what is the proper filePathColumn in my case. My cursor is returning null from this query

Comment: There is no proper collum. You should not use content resolver and so. You have a string with the path already. Only it starts with "file://". Remove that and you are done.

Comment: Yes, uri.getPath() gets the work done, but is it a good practice?

Comment: If uri.toString() starts with "file://" then yes. If uri.toString() starts with "content://" then not. Then use your old code. So just check and handle accordingly. But why do you need a file system path? You can use the uri directly for a lot of things.